# [followup question]Route request based on ssl_client_verify in Nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

This is follow up question on this topic - [Route request based on ssl_client_verify in Nginx ingress controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745222/route-request-based-on-ssl-client-verify-in-nginx-ingress-controller)

I have similar query, where we have multiple paths, for example below ones, if `ssl_client_verify` is successful  requests going to /v1 or /v2  will be happening, how do we redirect the request to /v1/ or /v2 if `ssl_client_verify` is SUCCESS ? Will this `set $service_name   "yes1-mtls-backend,yes2-mtls-backend";` work ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dynamic-upstream
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/ca-cert
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: optional
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "3"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
        set $service_name   "yes1-mtls-backend,yes2-mtls-backend";
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: no-mtls-backend
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: yes1-mtls-backend
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /v2
        pathType: Prefix

  - host: xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: yes2-mtls-backend
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /v1 
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: I guess in your case you need to use a nested if condition or simply remove the if condition and `no-mtls-backend`. In the post which you have provided as a reference, `fardin` is using the if block to set the hostname if the verification is successful. So, in your case if you want to follow the same you need to have a nested if condition. First if condition is for checking whether the authentication is successful and the second condition is to check the path it belongs to or you can set `auth-tls-verify-client: true` and remove the if block and no condition.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni: can't remove `no-mtls-backend` as `no-mtls-backend` is  "healthcheck" endpoint and used for alerts.So we want to keep `no-mtls-backend` which doesnt require mTLS,other endpoints requires mTLS.Please give an example of `nested`if condition for this usecase ?

Comment: if ($ssl\_client\_verify = SUCCESS) { if($request\_uri \~\* "/v1\*"){ set $service\_name   "yes1-mtls-backend"; } if($request\_uri \~\* "/v2"){ set $service\_name   "yes2-mtls-backend"; } }

Comment: You can correct the regex matching to your application url. I have only given a rough outline on this. Try this and let us know if this works for you and revert back if you are still facing some issues.